# SQL RLS for NIST compliance

Tags: compliance, sql-server, nist

Is there specific NIST documentation advising about implementing [MS SQL Row-Level security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017#UseCases) for 800-53 compliance?

Comment: you mean, besides "access control"?

Comment: Have you done any research? 800-53 is well-documented.

Comment: I found this in a couple minutes: "Access control policies ... control access between active entities or subjects ... and passive entities or objects (e.g., ... ***records*** ...) in information systems." https://nvd.nist.gov/800-53/Rev4/control/AC-3

Comment: @schroeder , For access control.   I searched the website for `SQL row level` security implementation for SQL. Couldn't locate anything specific.

Looking for a specific reference to Microsoft SQL Row level security implementation as a requirement or recommendation for NIST compliance.

Comment: There will not be such specific, and vendor-narrow advice

Comment: @schroeder , Then is there anything specifying **ROW-LEVEL** RBAC measures' implementation for SQL in general?

Or is there any other frameworks like NYDFS, SKID etc that emphasizes on **ROW-LEVEL**  ?